# How to check if a string contains multiple numbers in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer

I am wanting to see if a string contains multiple numbers in the string itself and to have it print out the number itself.

Example:

```
def number_in_string(string):
    #code to check for a number
    number=int(123445) #in the instance with x
    number=int(24) #in the instance of y
    number=int(32) #in the instance of z
    return(number)

x="123445"
y="rand24chars"
z="rand3chars2"
number=number_in_string(x) #just as an example but I would run through all of the variables ideally
print(number)
```

I know the code to be able to check if the string has 1 digit, and would be able to add multiple numbers or just multiply them with a bit more code, but I am unaware of how to do a multidigit number in the same fashion.

Code for 1 digit:

```
number=[]
def chars(y,number):
    for i in range(y):
        if (i.isdigit()==True):
            number=number.append(i)
        else:
            continue
    return(number)

y="alkfjh3432,skj"
number=chars(y,number)
print(number) #[3,4,3,2]
```

If anyone can help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code for 1 digit does not work. What do you mean by *multidigit number*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.

```
def digits(nbr):
    val = 0
    for i in nbr:
        if i.isdigit():
            val = val * 10 + int(i)
    return val

y="alkfjh3432,skj"
number=digits(y)
print(number)
```

Prints `3432`.

Please note that the loop needed to go through the characters of the string.  It's not a use for `range`.  Also note that `if` and `return` statements in Python do not use parentheses.  Also note that when you do `if x==True:` it always reads better to say `if x:`.  Same with `if x==False:` which should be `if not x:`.

Answer (score 0):

simple as it sounds, iterate through string, if the character contains digit append it to the result list:

```py
from typing import List

def get_digits_from_string(string: str) -> List[int]:
    result = []
    for character in string:
        if character.isdigit():
            result.append(int(character))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

To search in a string, regex will go a very long way. With regex, you can simply search for all the number characters `\d` :

```py
import re

def get_digits(x):
  return re.findall(r'\d', x)
```

More here: https://www.regular-expressions.info